# mysqli_connect ( ) vs @mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysql

In looking at various mysql and php code, I've seen the database connection written either with an ampersand or without:

```
$db = mysqli_connect (db_host, db_user, db_pw, db_name);
```

vs

```
$db = @mysqli_connect (db_host, db_user, db_pw, db_name);
```

Is there are reason some developers use the @ and others do not?

Thank you

Comment: `@` suppresses error messages. It's generally considered poor practice - if something goes wrong with connecting to the database, you should be dealing with it appropriately, and not hiding the fact.

Answer (score 7):

`@` is the [error suppression operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) and hides warnings / errors that the function outputs. Using it is generally considered as bad practice.

While developing, the error messages are there for a reason. If you don't want to display the error messages, turn off error reporting in your `php.ini` configuration and log them instead.